# How to delete all the files in sub directories older than x days and not created on Sunday in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I wanted to find the solution where deleting all the files in the **subdirectories** as well older than x days and should not delete if the file was created on **Sunday**

My Main Folder Path is C:\Main_Folder within than I have the structure,

```
+---Sub_Folder_1
|       Day1.xlsx
|       Day2.xlsx
|       Day3.xlsx
|
+---Sub_Folder_2
|       Day1.xlsx
|       Day2.xlsx
|       Day3.xlsx
|
\---Sub_Folder_3
        Day1.xlsx
        Day2.xlsx
        Day3.xlsx
```

I tried with below code but it deletes even subdirectories as well

```
import os, shutil
folder = 'C:\\Main_Folder\\'
for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
    file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            os.unlink(file_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(file_path): shutil.rmtree(file_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to check the time a file was last edited you want to include two libraries. `import os.path, time`

First thing you have to take into consideration is which field you want to use from a file, for example:

```
print("Last Modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("file.txt")))
# Last Modified: Mon Jul 30 11:10:21 2018
print("Created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime('file.txt')))
# Created: Tue Jul 31 09:13:23 2018
```

So you will have to parse this line and look for the fields you want to consider older than x date. Take into consideration to look through the string for `Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat` for the week values.

```
fileDate = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime('file.txt'))
if 'Sun' not in fileDate:
  # Sun for Sunday is not in the time string so check the date and time
```

You will have to loop through the files in the subdirectory, check the Created time or Last Modified time, whichever you prefer, and then parse the date and time fields from the string and compare to your case, removing those which you seem fitting to be deleted.

Comment: i loved your elaboration

Comment: @Xavid Thanks for the Answer I was facing other issue was like it was deleting subdirectory itself, I wanted to make sure only deleting the files and the folder itself as well, How to approach this

Comment: so the os library has two nice functions, os.isfile(currentPathHere) and os.isdir(currentPathHere). These two are boolean functions, you can use these, if isdir is true, then change the path to look into the contents of this folder, and repeat the process. You can make this a recursive function that recursively goes into every single folder starting from the root inward, and looks at files, removing those that meet your criteria.